# Is it possible to use AWS DMS without Oracle Log Miner or Binary Reader?

Tags: amazon-web-services, oracle, endpoint, aws-dms

I'm using AWS DMS to migrate data from an Oracle Source Endpoint into an S3 Target Endpoint. I do not have administrative control over the Source Endpoint, and those who do are reluctant to provide `GRANT` privileges to read `V_$LOG` etc.

Is there a way to use DMS to move data from Source to Target without having [these kinds](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Source.Oracle.html#CHAP_Source.Oracle.Self-Managed.BinaryReaderPrivileges) of `GRANT`s?

I tried disabling CDC options altogether by setting `UseBFile` to `false` and `UseLogminerReader` to `false`. However, at least one is reenabled due to the `false` on the other. The result is

`Test Endpoint failed: Application-Status: 1020912, Application-Message: No permissions to access V$LOG Endpoint initialization failed.`

Comment: As far as I know only two projects managed to reverse-engineer content of Oracle's archivelog files: GoldenGate(lately bought by Oracle) and Shareplex. All other 3rd party CDC tools use LogMinner internally. So I'm afraid you have no chance to use that without logminer privs.

Comment: That's the thing -- we just want DMS for moving data, not for CDC. If there's a way to use it just for scheduled transfers, that would fit the bill

Comment: DMS is not Oracle's technology it is something made up by Amazon. It has to rely on Oracle's internal technologies. Unfortunately Amazon is quite cryptic when it is to explain what their technology is and how it works. In case of Oracle you can use Datapump(expdp/impdp), Dataguard(replication based on physical logs), CDC(logical replication based on information extracted from physical archivelogs). Amazon's DMS is just a wrapper around these technologies.